# start a file from another drive

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a script that opens games and programs using tkinter and sqlite3.

The problem is that everytime I try to open a game, I get an error message that tells me that the fila can't be found. Is it possible to open files from another drive in python or do I have to do this with shortcuts?

```
cnct = sqlite3.connect("./data.db")
csr = cnct.cursor()
csr.execute("SELECT FROM progs WHERE names = ?", (prog_name,))
prog_path = csr.fetchone()
os.startfile(f"{prog_path}")
```

prog_path = A:\Fallout 4\Fallout4.exe

I used a sqlite3 database to store the names asociated to the path.
And the script is in the C: drive while the game is in the A: drive.

Comment: Please show a sample of your code.

Comment: Also, it might be an issue related to python's working directory, please do a research on that

Comment: Make sure of the following things

1.Try to give the absolute path.

2. make sure the user from which you are running the python script have read permissions to the file.